# chmod operation not permitted on /var/www/ SSH raspbian

Tags: ssh, permissions, apache-http-server, raspbian

I am trying to setup a simple Apache web server over SSH in Raspbian but cannot obtain access to `/var/www`. I have tried these commands to obtain write permission:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
chmod go-rwx /var/www
```

For `chmod` I got this error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var/www’: Operation not permitted
```

For `chown` it didn't display any message, and appeared to do nothing. To recap, I am trying to figure out how to obtain access to use these commands and also to obtain access to that directory. I am logged in on the default user pi and haven't set a root password. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about sudo chmod..   And why does your example do sudo chown but not sudo chmod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `sudo` with `chmod` as well:

```
sudo chmod go-rwx /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @EugenRieck answer, this is not working because you are" I logged in on the default user pi" - you need to be root to execute this command.

You can either follow his advice by prefixing the command with sudo, which will execute it as root, or you can get root privileges (sudo /bin/bash or su) to become root before executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you have to have root privileges to remove /var/swap.

If you do have them but still doesn't work, chances are the folder is still actively used as swap folder. Supposing you have just edited the /etc/dphys-swapfile, a reboot can help.